# How to implement an association with restrictions

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraint, check-constraints

I'm working on an SQL database of useful plants. I'd like to be able to allow users to annotate the plants with a set of hierarchical categories and tags. For example:

- **category:** medicine

  - **body part:** stomach
  - **disease:** IBS

An initial database structure could be:

**Plant**

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ginger | medicine |

**PlantTags**

| id | plant_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

**Tags**

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | body part | stomach |
| 2 | disease | IBS |

I would like to restrict the categories and tags that can be used together. For example, one should only be able to apply the `body part` and `disease` tags if the `medicine` category is selected. Furthermore, one should only be able to select the `disease: IBS` tag if the `body part: stomach` tag is selected.

Put another way, I want a way to specify which combinations of tags are valid.

Is this possible at the database level?

**EDIT:**

Users should also be able to categorise a plant without tagging it. For example:

**Plant**

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | cedar | timber |

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an example of a set of tags that should not be allowed:

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | body part | stomach |
| 2 | disease | pneumonia |

`pneumonia` is a disease of the lungs, not the stomach, so having the two tags `stomach` and `pneumonia` should not be allowed.

Comment: Please select only one DBMS. If you need for both then create 2 separate questions. These DBMSs instruments are too different.

Comment: Sorry, I've put it as MySQL. But a high-level conceptual answer would be fine

Comment: Conceptual answer seems to be in disabling direct access to the data. All data changes will be performed via stored procedures which realizes and checks any logiс which you need. Fast implementation may be in trigger logic usage, but it is difficult-to-expand/check/control.

Comment: I think the problem could also be solved with changes in design only (adding new tables and foreign keys).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ OP needs in group check (check values combination in a group of `PlantTags` EAV table) - I doubt that additional tables/FKs may solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this, but the most simplest way to enforce this would probably be to create a **dimension combination** table. Such a table is pre-filled with all valid possible combinations (by `id`) and then that is the source of your application's controls (such as dropdowns, etc) because as you filter on one dimension in that table, only valid entries for the remaining dimensions will be available.

For example, your **dimension combinations** table would have a `plant_category_id` column and a `tag_type_id` and maybe a second `tag_type_id2` column (or if you normalized your `Tags` table, the column naming would be a little better in the **dimensions combinations** table).

---

The other thing you can do is implement a complex [**check constraint**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) (possibly with a function) but this is probably more work than it's worth, and will depend on which implementation of MySQL and version you're using.

---

The third way is handling the logic in **stored procedures** that manage data access via the logic you want to implement, but probably would also be a lot of work, especially to maintain over time. So the first suggestion that makes it table driven would be my first pick.

Comment: I like that suggestion! Could you explain a little more about normalising the `Tags` table? I'm not sure I understand why `tag_type_id2` is necessary.

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza I suggested normalizing because you said one of the requirements is that multiple `Tags` need constraints on each other too, e.g. `IBS` only goes with `stomach`. So in your **dimensions combinations** table you'd need a way to repsent them both in the same row, which can be done via `tag_type_id` and `tag_type_id2` **or** if you normalize the `Tags` table since they are different types of tags technically, then you could have a `BodyTags` and a `DiseaseTags` table, and then your columns in your **dimensions combinations** table now become `body_tag_id` and `disease_tag_id`...

Comment: ...instead which improves readability. Also normalizing your `Tags` table improves query performance as well, *generally*. But you don't have to normalize if you don't want and still go with my first naming convention instead.

Comment: Ah I see - the issue there is there are 20+ types of tag, so then the combinations table would have 20+ columns... unless there were a different combinations table for every pair of types. For me I think that is too much normalisation...! But in any case I think your solution works.

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza Yea it just depends on your preference. It's not unusual for a **dimensions combination** table to be wide and denormalized in a sense. This is actually a pretty common design pattern in the financial world. But using the generic version with just `tag_type_id` and `tag_type_id2` (nullable) works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can model a hierarchy by using a foreign key that references the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE tag
             (id integer,
              parent integer,
              key varchar(64),
              value varchar(64),
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (parent)
                          REFERENCES tag
                                     (id));
```

If a plant is then associate with one of the tags, all the tags higher in the hierarchy will be implicitly associated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this will solve my question. Firstly, users should be able to select a category without choosing any tags. Secondly, this doesn't allow me to specify which combinations of tags are valid.

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza: Well, it perfectly solves your example. Maybe you can [edit] the question and come up with another example that cannot be solved by that approach.

Comment: done, hope that is clear

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza: Edit my answer. Of course instead of just associating the leaves of the tag forest, users can also use any node, also a root node. Still solves your problem.

Comment: I think there is still something missing - your answer doesn't provide a way to specify which combinations of tags are valid. I have updated my question to give an example of two tags that shouldn't be used together. They are both children of the `medicine` category.

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza: It does. Just don't put `pneumonia` as a child under the `stomach` tag.

Comment: So `pneumonia` would have to be a child of the `lungs` tag? That works, but for diseases that can affect multiple body parts, I would need to create duplicate tags. For example, I would need a separate `cancer` tag for the different body parts that could be affected. This is perhaps a minor point :)

Comment: @Joaquimd'Souza: Yeah that is a point indeed. That can be probably circumvented by using something like an "all-body-parts" tag or directly linking "cancer" to "medicine" and for special form of cancer tags like "lung-cancer" that then link to the respective body parts. But of course that can impede a search over the tags for a user unaware of this detail.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it does work but I think I will choose the "TagCombination" answer below. This is because my team is against putting the tags into a hierarchy.